# Table row in sql as new table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table with ID,Name,Date and Category.
I want Category to be also a table,with rows ID and Name.
how can I do this?

Comment: That is too broad. Read a tutorial on foreign keys and n-to-m relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello This Is Kind OF a big Conceptual question You Should learn more about this .I am adding some ans for your question the table creation Query

```
   CREATE TABLE Info_table(
   ID   INT          NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
   Date  date        NOT NULL,
   Category_ID INT references CATEGORIES(ID),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    );
    /*Category Table */
    CREATE TABLE Category_table(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   Category_NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,    
   PRIMARY KEY (ID) /*Primary Key which is used as a foreign key in the first table  */
   );
```

I am also adding a sample picture related to this query see that hope It helps You [image: RelationShip]

Comment: Thanks a lot,Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

Assume, InitialTable is your current table and we are going to create a new table named NewTable.

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable
(
    ID int,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Category int -- I don't knopw the type of category
)

INSERT INTO NewTable(ID, Name, Category)
SELECT ID, Name, Category FROM InitialTable
```

If you want to drop Category column from your initial table then use following

```
ALTER TABLE InitialTable
DROP COLUMN Category
```

Answer (score 1):

For **SQL Server**:

I assume that you have something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (
    ID int IDENTITY (1,1),
    [Name] nvarchar(max),
    [Date] date,
    [Category] nvarchar(max),
CONSTRAINT PK_SomeTable_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
)

INSERT INTO SomeTable ([Name], [Date], [Category]) VALUES 
('w',GETDATE(),'Category1'),
('q',GETDATE(),'Category2')
```

So you will have this in `SomeTable`:

```
ID  Name    Date        Category
1   w       2016-10-02  Category1
2   q       2016-10-02  Category2
```

And you need to put all `category`s in new table (dictionary) each category  will have unique id and in `SomeTable` you need to store only category ids.

At first create new table:

```
CREATE TABLE Category (
    CatId int IDENTITY(1,1), --or unuqueidentifier or whatever
    CategoryName nvarchar(max),
CONSTRAINT PK_Category_CatId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CatId)
)
```

Insert unique category names in new table:

```
INSERT INTO Category (CategoryName)
SELECT DISTINCT [Category]
FROM SomeTable
```

Add new column to `SomeTable`:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD CatId int NULL
```

Update values in new column:

```
UPDATE s
SET CatId = c.CatId
FROM SomeTable s
INNER JOIN Category c
    ON s.[Category] = c.CategoryName
```

Drop `Category` column:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable DROP COLUMN [Category]
```

Add FK:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable  
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SomeTable_Category FOREIGN KEY (CatId)  
    REFERENCES Category (CatId) ;
```

Make `CatId` in `SomeTable` not nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ALTER COLUMN CatId int NOT NULL;
```

After that you will have:

```
--SomeTable
ID  Name    Date        CatId
1   w       2016-10-02  1
2   q       2016-10-02  2

--Category
CatId   CategoryName
1       Category1
2       Category2
```

Comment: Thank You,Nice answer,I'll try it